# The getter red was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the color picker plugin in flutter but the dialog box or the color picker itself is running into an error. Here's the code for the color picker dialog:

```
Color selectedColor;
  double strokeWidth;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    selectedColor = Colors.black;
    strokeWidth = 2.0;
  }

  void selectColor(){
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_)=>
        AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Pick a color!'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ColorPicker(
              pickerColor: selectedColor,
              showLabel: true,
              onColorChanged: (color){
                this.setState(() {
                  selectedColor = color;
                });
              },

            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
                onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
                child: Text("Close")
            )
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```

And here's the error I'm running into:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#f296e](state: RawGestureDetectorState#9ea30(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
The getter 'red' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: red

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///E:/nush/painting_app/lib/main.dart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Debugger to step through your code and see when "The getter 'red' was called on null" actually happens.